# Converting string to 2D list

Tags: python

```
def convert_to_list(VertexList):
    VerticesList = []
    items = VertexList.split(';')
    for item in items:
        i = item.split(',')
        SubList = []
        for item in i:
            SubList.append(item)
        VerticesList.append(SubList)
    return VerticesList
```

This code converts string in this format to a 2D list. However, I am sure it can be optimized.

```py
Input -> '1,2,4,5,6,7;2,3,4,5,6,7,8;1,2,4,5,6,8'
Output -> [['1', '2', '4', '5', '6', '7'], ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'], ['1', '2', '4', '5', '6', '8']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a comprehension.

```py
inp = '1,2,4,5,6,7;2,3,4,5,6,7,8;1,2,4,5,6,8'

print([s.split(',') for s in inp.split(';')])
```

Results in

```
[['1', '2', '4', '5', '6', '7'], ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'], ['1', '2', '4', '5', '6', '8']]
```

This is smaller, easier to read code, which is part of the optimization I expect you were looking for.  It doesn't loop through things any fewer times, but it's executing fewer assignments, using less temporary variabels, and making fewer function calls (i.e. `append()`).  Maybe some of those calls are being made behind the scenes in the comprehension, but you should be taking advantage of whatever optimizations Python does to its comprehensions in terms of what functions calls are made.

--update--

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67921750/14757226) for a performance analysis of the OP and this answer.

-- update 2 --

To convert all strings to int, you can use `map` or another comprehension.

```py
inp = '1,2,4,5,6,7;2,3,4,5,6,7,8;1,2,4,5,6,8'

print([list(map(int, s.split(','))) for s in inp.split(';')])
```

or

```py
inp = '1,2,4,5,6,7;2,3,4,5,6,7,8;1,2,4,5,6,8'

print([[int(c) for c in s.split(',')] for s in inp.split(';')])
```

Comment: Please briefly explain *how does this optimize the existing code?* As OP is looking for optimizing the existing code.

Comment: So elegant! Thanks :)

Comment: Can we also convert the characters to int in the same line of code?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution, but only a comparison of the optimality of the above codes in terms of actual performance:

```
from timeit import Timer

code1 = """\
def convert_to_list(VertexList):
    VerticesList = []
    items = VertexList.split(';')
    for item in items:
        i = item.split(',')
        SubList = []
        for item in i:
            SubList.append(item)
        VerticesList.append(SubList)
    return VerticesList
inp = '1,2,4,5,6,7;2,3,4,5,6,7,8;1,2,4,5,6,8'
convert_to_list(inp)
"""

code2 = """\
inp = '1,2,4,5,6,7;2,3,4,5,6,7,8;1,2,4,5,6,8'
out = [s.split(',') for s in inp.split(';')]
"""

t = Timer(stmt=code1)
time1 = t.timeit()  # 1000000 iteration by default
print(f"Original time:{round(time1, 6)} sec.")

t = Timer(stmt=code2)
time2 = t.timeit()  # 1000000 iteration by default
print(f"New time: {round(time2, 6)} sec.")

print(f'New solution faster in = {round(time1 / time2, 1)} times')
```

Output:

```
Original time:1.812856 sec.
New time: 0.741987 sec.
New solution faster in = 2.4 times
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Great learning opportunity :)